# Natural Language Processing - visual definition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

May be a stupid thought/question.

Is there any computer branch/system in NLP, AI, or ML where I can define basic words using images. For example I link 'point', 'line', 'angel', or triangle' etc. with relevant 2d vector images. Instead of defining their definition in English again. Because, To explain below sentence to the system

> This is triangle.

I need to define: 'this', 'is', 'triangle'. Now each definition will have more words. I need to define all of them too and so on. It'll never end since I'll fall in loop of definitions.

Specially If I need to explain 'Left', 'Right'.

Comment: I am nominating to close as too broad. Just to clear up the assumptions of the question would amount to a significant essay. But to point to a basic problem, how would you distinguish the image of "an angle" from an image of "two rays extending from a point"? There are certainly systems for reasoning about geometry and axioms (though not AFAIK in an NLP framework) but then this should be closed as asking for pointers to external resources.

Comment: @tripleee, I agree. But I couldn't find any better place to ask this question. But that's fine. I'll google more. I'll really appreciate if you know some place for this discussion, suggest me. Thanks